# How to programatically configure proxy settings using metro webservices client

Tags: microsoft-metro, glassfish-3, webservices-client

I have a requirement where I need to set the proxy setting programatically using metro webservices client. Can any one suggest which API I need to user in order to set the proxy host, port.